# django conjunctive filter __in query

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Consider an array of Tags, T.

Each PhotoSet has a many-to-many relationship to Tags.

We also have a filter, F (consisting of a set of Tags), and we want to return all PhotoSets who have ALL the tags contained in F.

i.e,. if F = ['green', 'dogs', 'cats'], we want every PhotoSet instance that has *all* the tags in F.

Naturally

```
PhotoSet.objects.filter(tags__in=F)
```

Does not do the trick, since it returns *every* PhotoSet contain *any* member of F.

I see it's possible to use similar things using "Q" expressions, but that only seemed for a finite amount of conjunctive parameters. Is this something that can be done using a list comprehension??

Thanks in advance!

EDIT -- SOLUTION:

I found the solution using an obvious way. Simply chaining filters...

```
results = PhotoSets.objects
for f in F:
  results = results.filter(tags__in=[f])
results = results.all()
```

Was staring me in the face the whole time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little quick and dirty, but it'll do the trick:

```
query = None
for tag in F:
    if query is None:
        query = Q(tags=tag)
    else:
        query &= Q(tags=tag)

PhotoSet.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'd try that if the solution I figured out didn't work. Which BTW, do you know which approach is most efficient?

Comment: They should be comparable in efficiency. Either way, the database is only actually hit once and the queries should be roughly the same.